# How to load a glTF file in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, gltf

So after spending time looking around, I am not sure how I would even go about loading and using a glTF file I have found and want to use for my OpenGL ES 3.0 program.

Are there are loaders or am I charge of extracting all the data from the glTF file?

EDIT:

I am developing on Android API 24 with NDK to use OpenGL ES 3.0

Comment: Please specify which environment you're using, any existing loader is tied to this information.

Comment: There are a number of existing WebGL-based glTF loaders, but it sounds like you're not on the web.  Is this Android? iOS? Something else?  Also note that glTF 2.0 (under dev now) will be much more cross-platform than glTF 1.0, with added support for desktop, Vulkan, Direct3D, and more.  What platform are you interested in?

Comment: @rotoglup I am using Android API 24 and NDK to run OpenGL ES

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, as of today (April 2017), there is no easy/official way to load & draw a GLTF model in native/mobile environments - the webgl ecosystem is currently more friendly.

GLTF being quite young, you would have to find some code around, or build your own.

Another alternative would be to try to use [assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) to convert your GLTF model to a format that you can easily display.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ATW Vulkan Sample](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/blob/master/samples/apps/atw/scenes/scene_gltf.h) from Khronos Group